# Best jQuery drop-down nav Suckerfish alternative that works with Flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, drop-down-menu, navigation

I think that my Suckerfish drop-down navigation does not play well with flash. I've done everything I can think of, yet my drop-down navigation keeps displaying underneath my flash movie. If I replace the movie with an image, it displays just fine. Only when I use a flash movie does the navigation display underneath the flash movie. I have already added `wmode` and it still does not work:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

So I think my only solution left is to try and replace the navigation. So I am looking for a jQuery plugin that will replace my current navigation. My current navigation works like this:

1. It's a horizontal drop-down menu
2. When you hover over the menu, the first level drop-down menu appears
3. When you click on a link in the first level drop-down menu, a second level is revealed below the link that was clicked (not the right like most nav menus). Sort of like a vertical accordion menu.

Is there anything like this currently available? I can't think of anything else to try to make the nav appear on top of the flash movie.

Comment: Have you tried setting the z-index of the menu and the flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bah! I was forgetting one thing. You must set the window mode in **TWO** places! I am using the [SWFObject javascript plugin](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), so my HTML looks like the following.

In order for your navigation to appear on top of your flash movie, you must not forget to specify `wmode="opaque"` (or transparent) in the **second object tag**

```
<object id="homepage_slideshow" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="530" height="397">
    <param name="movie" value="flash/homepage_slideshow.swf" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/homepage_slideshow.swf" width="530" height="397" wmode="opaque">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!-- begin alternative content -->
    <img src="images/photos/homepage-placeholder-photo.jpg" width="530" height="397" alt="Get Moving Again!" />
    <!-- end alternative content -->
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```