# css menus not overlaying on top of flash piece, Internet Explorer only

Tags: html, css, flash

The site I'm working on uses the age-old CSS "[suckerfish](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns)" menus to do drop downs rather than Javascript or some other CSS solution.   On some of these pages there are flash pieces, and for Internet Explorer 8 only, the menus get "blocked" by the flash area.  After seeing questions related to this issue, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800056/best-jquery-drop-down-nav-suckerfish-alternative-that-works-with-flash) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428187/popup-menu-pops-under-flash-in-chrome-opera-and-safari), I tried both wmode="opaque" and wmode="transparent", which solved the problem for Chrome, Opera, and Safari.   Firefox worked without any wmode specification.

However, IE 8 isn't working with either of these ... the css menus don't overlay the flash. These flash elements don't have a position assigned to them, so assigning a z-index won't help as far as my understanding goes.

How do I make this work for IE 8?

Please note you can see this operation on two different pages, one with:

wmode="transparent" :   http://www.momentumnow.biz/mn/index.shtml   (problematic flash piece is named MN_Pres-2-A.swf)

wmode="opaque" : [www.momentumnow.biz/mn/benefits.shtml](http://www.momentumnow.biz/mn/benefits.shtml)  (problematic flash piece is named  Benefits-A.swf).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this code in the flash section for IE browser.

This is the code:

```
              <param name="play" value="true">
              <param name="loop" value="true">
                  <param name="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
              <!--<![endif]-->

              <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"> <img src="/mn/images/a-350x120.png" alt="Get Adobe Flash player version 9.0.28 or later"> </a>

              <!--[if !IE]>-->

            </object>
```

Comment: Did I make a mistake?  It doesn't seem to be working?  Added the "param" to both the two pages.  On the second one I tried opaque.

Comment: Have you insert "<param name="wmode" VALUE="transparent">". It is not working.

Comment: Thanks, I put in: <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> on the 1st page, and <param name="wmode" value="opaque"> on the second page.  I'm not seeing a typo, are you?

Comment: In the 1st page issue fixed or not?

Comment: Yah, it did, thanks.  I appreciate the help.  Sorry, originally when I posted last I didn't think it fixed it, but I made a mistake in the update.  Now that's corrected and it indeed works.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After  Shalinisubramani's help, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe) which may be of interest to you, comparing opaque and transparent.  I ended up using the former per the second answer of the post.